# how to use python list comprehension/ dictionary to print each column as an unique variable

Tags: python, list, csv, pandas, dictionary

Assume we have a csv

```
PROPERTY_ID,CLIENT_ID,FROM_YEAR
1,5,2015
2,6,2015
3,9,2015
4,9,2015
```

I am trying to pass each unique combination of CLIENT_ID, PROPERTY_ID,FROM_YEAR into a dictionary or list, so I can put each "PROPERTY_ID,CLIENT_ID,FROM_YEAR" pair into MySQL queries:

```
SELECT * FROM client_5 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 1 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;

SELECT * FROM client_6 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 2 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;

SELECT * FROM client_9 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 3 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;

SELECT * FROM client_9 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 4 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;
```

From the variable point of view :

```
1st round:
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=5,1,2015

2nd round
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=6,2,2015

3rd round
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=9,3,2015

4th round
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=9,4,2015
```

I have tried to use list comprehension:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df2=df.apply(tuple, 1).unique().tolist()

for CLIENT_ID in [x[0] for x in df2]:

    CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID.astype('str')

    print "SELECT * FROM client"+CLIENT_ID

    for PROPERTY_CODE in [y[1] for y in df2]:

        PROPERTY_CODE=PROPERTY_CODE.astype('str')

        print "WHERE PROPERTY_ID = "+PROPERTY_CODE
```

it returns the following, which is not we are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM client_5
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 1
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 2
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 3
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 4
```

Could someone enlighten? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `pandas`? Only to parse the csv?

Comment: Just iterate over the data frame, build your queries and `add` them to a pre-built `set`. When you're done creating the queries then you execute them. The `set` eliminates duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:-

```
import csv 

with open('fileName.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:

        #print row
        print """SELECT * FROM client_%s WHERE PROPERTY_ID = %s and FROM_YEAR = %s;"""%(row[1],row[0],row[2])
```

Comment: It is better to manually capture the heading at the beginning `head = next(row)` before using the for-loop, rather than adding a hook inside the loop that slows down each iteration. Regardless, I think using the `csv` module is the way to go here.

Comment: csv module is way easier in this case.  I think I put my head into pandas too much in  this case and it becomes a rabbit hole lol.  The answer is actually very simple >.<.  Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `format`

```
fstr = '$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR={CLIENT_ID},{PROPERTY_ID},{FROM_YEAR}'
df.drop_duplicates().apply(lambda x: fstr.format(**x), 1)

0    $CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=5,1,2015
1    $CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=6,2,2015
2    $CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=9,3,2015
3    $CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=9,4,2015
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `apply` with `set` and `list`:

```
L = list(set(df.apply(lambda x: 'SELECT * FROM client_{} WHERE PROPERTY_ID = {} and FROM_YEAR = {};'.format(x['CLIENT_ID'], x['PROPERTY_ID'], x['FROM_YEAR']),1)))

print (L)
['SELECT * FROM client_5 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 1 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;', 
 'SELECT * FROM client_9 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 3 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;',
 'SELECT * FROM client_9 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 4 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;', 
 'SELECT * FROM client_6 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 2 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;']
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy implement with `.format` method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
rows = df.apply(tuple, 1).unique().tolist()

for (prop_id, client_id, year) in rows:
    print("SELECT * FROM client_{client_id} WHERE property_id = {prop_id} AND from_year = {year}".format(
        prop_id=prop_id,
        client_id=client_id,
        year=year
    ))
```

In Python 3.6 you can use string interpolation:

```
for (prop_id, client_id, year) in rows:
    print(f"SELECT * FROM client_{client_id} WHERE property_id = {prop_id} AND from_year = {year}")
```